# Cannot play music from local filesystem, but can play from SD card

Tags: java, android, audio

I am developing a test app that does nothing else than play music. The idea behind this app is that normally you have a music player that takes ages to load and has all those extra gadgets and gizmos that nobody, or at least not you, uses. This app only plays music, period. And it loads almost instantly.

But I got something funny. I need to find a way for the user to select a song from the filesystem, but I haven't got that working yet, so I am using a fixed song URI to play it. When I put this song on the local filesystem(i.e. /storage/emulated/0/Music/SongName.mp3), the app crashes upon pressing the play button. But when I put the song on the SD card(i.e. /storage/extSdCard/Music/SongName.mp3) it works fine.

Well, I got it to work, but I don't know how or why it works. Normally I would be surprised and not touch that piece of code again so that it keeps working, but this time I am learning programming on Android and I want to know why it works.

This is the code for playing from the SD card(works):

```
p = new MediaPlayer();
p.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
p.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/extSdCard/Tests/Take Back The Night.mp3")));
p.prepare();
p.start();
```

And this is the code for playing from the local fs(does not work):

```
p = new MediaPlayer();
p.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
p.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Music/heybrother.mp3")));
p.prepare();
p.start();
```

As you can see, it's pretty much the same, so I concluded that there is probably something wrong in the URI. But I can't see any typos, and I retyped it multiple times. Is the URI malformed for this purpose?

Comment: p.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/yourdirectory/youraudiofile.mp3");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!

First, you need to get the path of the music folder like this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
              .getPath() + "/";
```

Then you can append the file name in the music folder:

```
String file = path + "ThatOneSong.mp3";
```

And then play it as normal. (Or you could do this in one long line but that's kind of cluttered.)